# filtering pages based on a page param in Hugo

Tags: hugo

I have a metadata field in my pages like so

```markdown
---
dateStartOfEvent: "2022-06-26T00:00:00+02:00"
type: event
---
```

I would like to:

1. collect all the pages whose **type: event**
   `{{- $cond1  := where .Site.RegularPages "Type" "event" }}`
   `{{- $events := $cond1 }}`
2. from the result of 1 above, I would like to find the pages whose **dateStartOfEvent** is after today
   `{{- $cond2  := where (time $events.Params.dateStartOfEvent).After now }}`
3. iterate over the first 10 events and list them
   `{{- $events_num := (.Site.Params.widgets.events_num | default 10) }}`
   `{{- range first $events_num $events }}`
   `...`

I am facing a problem in step 2 where I get the following error

`at <$events.Params.dateStartOfEvent>: can't evaluate field Params in type page.Pages`

Of course, I would like to do this all in one line, if possible, like I am used to in JS by chaining commands but I don't know if that is possible in `golang`

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question on Hugo's discourse website and learned that in-line transformations of keys are not possible in a where filter. The signature of the where filter is `where COLLECTION KEY [optional OPERATOR] MATCH`. In there, one can't transform the key as I was trying to do with the `time` function